# /home on a separated partition in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, directory, home-directory

Is home already on a different partition from / where the OS and system files are in 18.04 Ubuntu version?
How can I get it like that when I've got a 127 GB new partition for that purpose?
I cannot identify with the disks app where the home folder really is located.
Could you tell me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a clean install of Ubuntu without managing the partitions yourself, then `/home` directory is the part of your `"/ directory" i.e root directory`. Hence they both use the same disk space.

If you want to install your `/home` directory onto different partition then while installing the Ubuntu you should manage the partitions yourself.

There is an option where the Installer asks the user to **Install Ubuntu**, you should select **Something Else** option there and manage the partitions.

You should see your hard drive as `/dev/sda` (if you got only 1 hard drive in your system else there will be multiple drives like `/dev/sd#` '#' could be any letter corresponding to no. of drives you have)

You should make new partitions from **free space** and mount them to root and home directory.

Make a partition for your OS (where your root directory will be, should be at least 5 GB) and then a new partition for your home directory (this will be place for your personal files, give any size you feel like).

To mount the respective partition to the directories type the following in mount option :
`/` for root directory
`/home` for home directory

Then continue to install, you now have separate partitions for your root and home directory.

P.S.
You can also make a partition for swap space, its better to make one.
You can learn more about swap space from [here](https://opensource.com/article/18/9/swap-space-linux-systems)

Comment: +1 except for the paragraph about swap partitions: as of 17.04 Ubuntu uses a swap file and doesn't need a separate swap partition.

Comment: Is that so, thnx. for info @Jos :)